# How to align videos, their height and wifth and their progress bar on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I have a function that works fine and videos are played properly but these videos are shown in a single line but I want one video in one line and all the videos should have same width and height.

```
function appendReturnedVideos(data) {

    var $html = $();

    $.each(data.videos, function(index, element) { 
        $html = $html.add($("<video/>", { 
            height: 360,
            css: { 'max-width': 480},
            src: element,
            controls: true,
            preload: 'auto' 
        }));

        $("#videos").append($html);        
    });
}
```

HTML part:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="myElement">
    <div id="videos"> </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: can you replicate it in a fiddle? It doesnt have to have real videos, just put similar html and css

Comment: give me five minutes i ll try

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/farooqi111/wdyrpa89/3/

Comment: i havn't added jQuery kindly add it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `$("#videos").append($html);` add a break like

```
 $html = $html.add('<br/>');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wdyrpa89/4/)

Comment: again same problem. It doesn't take the video to next line